# Need help identifying a guitar

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, instruments, classical-guitar

I really like the sound and look of this classical acoustic. Can anyone help me identify it?

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about locating or naming a particular resource, sound, composition or instrument are often relevant only to the original asker & rarely useful to future readers. They are also an unsearchable resource.

Comment: I don't hear anything special about the instrument. The primary factors influencing the sound here are the tuning and arrangement, musician performance and recording. Classical guitars are typically identified by a card glued inside the soundhole, which we can't see here. If you're really determined, contact the musician, or perhaps they mention the guitar maker and model in an interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to id it from that video. There doesn't seem to be a mark on the headstock so the next most likely place to check is a label *inside* the guitar, usually right under the sound hole. The video doesn't seem to have any close ups that would let you see any such labels.

This page gives an interview where Robin Pecknold talks about the classical guitars he has used. https://www.guitarworld.com/features/fleet-foxes-robin-pecknold-shore

> ...64 Martin classical, I think it was a 00-18C or something ...Romeo classical guitar ...a different classical guitar in New York to finish up and that was an Armenian luthier, Manouk Papazian

That doesn't id the guitar in the video, but it gives you a sense of what he has used. Also, just a general tip, there a lots of pages devoted to listing well known guitarists gear. (Although you want to check how they verify their information.) And looking for interviews is another good what to find out about gear used, straight from the horse's mouth.

IMO it sounds like a typical classical guitar. No put down intended in saying that. Just suggesting that you can probably get *any* classical guitar of good quality and get a similar sound... unless you are a classical guitar tone aficionado.